# Character problem with endpoint '/{GROUP_ID}/feed' of Facebook API

Tags: python, python-3.x, facebook, facebook-graph-api

The code below works without error, but the posted text is cut off in Facebook as soon as a "&" character is found.

```py
TOKEN_ID = '<Token>'
GROUP_ID = '<group_id>'
headers   = { 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8;', }
msg = 'Automation test & Python script'
fb_url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/{GROUP_ID}/feed?message={msg}&access_token={TOKEN_ID}"
resp = requests.post(fb_url, headers=headers)
pprint(resp.json())
```

`return:` 'id': '686578895356485_972982316716140'}

I want to post `Automation test & Python script` and the post only have `Automation test` as you can see with the [capture with problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DNFI.png)

It seems to be an encoding problem, but I don't see how to fix it.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's because you neglected to apply proper URL encoding to the parameter values you are inserting into that URL.

Comment: example of proper URL encoding would be helpful here

Comment: @CBroe Yes, this is what I said in my post with my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works. As supposed, it was an encoding problem.

```py
import urllib.parse
 
TOKEN_ID = '<Token>'
GROUP_ID = '<group_id>'
headers   = { 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8;', }
msg = 'Automation test & Python script'
msg = urllib.parse.quote_plus(msg)
fb_url = f"https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/{GROUP_ID}/feed?message={msg}&access_token={TOKEN_ID}"
resp = requests.post(fb_url, headers=headers)
pprint(resp.json())
```

If you have something better or cleaner, I'll take it.